# Pointer as generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics, void-pointers, unsafe

I have a bunch of external C functions that in C# become something like this:

```
public extern static int clGetDeviceInfo(
    IntPtr device, 
    uint param_name, 
    IntPtr param_value_size, 
    void* param_value, 
    out IntPtr param_value_size_ret);
```

Because there are a bunch of similar looking function, I wanted to create a method which reads the data provided by these C functions. This is what I went with:

```
unsafe public static ErrorCode GetInfoString(
    IntPtr handle, uint property, 
    Func<IntPtr, uint, IntPtr, void*, IntPtr, int> infoFunc, 
    out string value)
{
    // reading logic
}
```

My problem is that C# does not allow me to use the `void*` as a generic argument of `Func`. Is there any way around this problem?

I can neither change the signature of external C function nor the signature of the C# function (I'm using a library).

Comment: "IntPtr" doesn't mean "pointer to an int", it means "pointer at least as big as an int". It's about equivalent to a C `void *`.

Comment: My problem is that C# generics won't allow me to use a pointer (in this case a void pointer) as a type argument of `Func`.

Comment: Can you define a custom delegate type instead of reusing `Func`?

Comment: Frankly, i was semi-surprised C# lets you say `void *` at all. The places you're using it, i've generally seen `IntPtr`s used instead.

Comment: Your use of `IntPtr` is weird in this method; can you explain why you have what looks like a *size* being represented as an `IntPtr` ? What's the signature of the method in C?

Comment: @cHao: You said that backwards. `IntPtr` means **integer at least as big as a pointer**, not the other way around.

Comment: @EricLippert: Yeah, that. :/

Answer (score 7):

> My problem is that C# does not allow me to use the `void*` as a generic argument of Func. Is there any way around this problem?

Yes. Use `IntPtr` *everywhere* that you are at present using `void*`.  Don't use `void*` in C# if you can possibly avoid it.

> I can't change the signature of the functions I'm trying to pass as arguments, so that won't work.

Sure it does.  You have

```
public extern static int clGetDeviceInfo(
    IntPtr device, 
    uint param_name, 
    IntPtr param_value_size, 
    void* param_value, 
    out IntPtr param_value_size_ret);
```

You can't change it because it is in a library. Fine. What *can* you change? You can change your own code. So *write your own code!* You're a computer programmer; that's what you do:

```
private static int MyClGetDeviceInfo(
    IntPtr device, 
    uint param_name, 
    IntPtr param_value_size, 
    IntPtr param_value, 
    out IntPtr param_value_size_ret)
{
  unsafe 
  {
    return clGetDeviceInfo(device, param_name, param_value_size,
      (void*)param_value, out param_value_size_ret);
  }
}
```

There, now you have a method that has a signature you can make a `Func` out of.

Comment: I can't change the signature of the functions I'm trying to pass as arguments, so that won't work.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: What does that matter? You can change *your own code*.   See edit.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll pass on wrapping each of these functions. There's got to be a better way and in fact, there is using a delegate.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: I would not characterize that solution as "better". **Don't use `void*` in C# if you can possibly avoid it**.  Passing around raw pointers is not idiomatic in C#; hide them behind `IntPtr`s as much as you possibly can when you are interoperating with C libraries. Better: write custom interop libraries that are *better than the ones you are using at present*. You want to capture the semantics of the operation in the interop layer, not expose raw pointers all over the place.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: I have been programming professionally in C# for a long, long time and the number of times I have had to use `void*` in non-test production code is *zero times*. Think very carefully about what you are doing here; misuse of pointer types in C# has serious consequences because you are effectively disabling the memory and type safety systems. You've probably spent more time typing up this question than it would take you to implement a set of cleaner wrappers around all your unmanaged APIs; take the time to do it right, and it will pay dividends later.

Comment: The nice thing about Eric's approach is that callers into Eric's new function need not be compiled with /unsafe .  This means you can place all these wrappers into a separate `unsafe` assembly and not need your callers to be `unsafe`.  Any time you are forced to work with `unsafe` code, you should segregate it as much as possible.  Personally, I've found it very rare to use third-party, non-C# code without having all calls to it go through my own C# wrapper, a wrapper which is usually in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcinJuraszek pointed out:

> Can you define a custom delegate type instead of reusing `Func`

Yes, I can. Using a delegate works for me.

```
unsafe public delegate int GetInfoMethod(
    IntPtr handle, uint param_name, IntPtr param_value_size, 
    void* param_value, out IntPtr param_value_size_ret);

unsafe public static ErrorCode GetInfoString(
    IntPtr handle, uint property, 
    GetInfoMethod infoFunc, 
    out string value)
{
    // reading logic
}
```